# Russian URI using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, url-encoding, encodeuricomponent, cyrillic

I have a link with half part in English and other half in Russian character.

ex: http://www.xxx.xx/?card=1234&/русский/как-это-сделать/

When I do a `encodeURIComponent(document.URL)` inside java script I get something like this
http://www.xxxx.xx/card=1234&/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B

How to do a url encode inside java script so that I get a meaningful url to send (Which is exactly like the document URL, with the Russian character).

Thanks ; :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Javascript code solves your problem:

```
encodeURI("http://www.xxx.xx/?card=1234&/русский/как-это-сделать/")
```

Comment: Please define the meaning of "meaningful to send". What exactly you do with the encoded string?

Comment: How to do a url encode inside java script so that I get a meaningful url to send (Which is exactly like the document URL, with the Russian character)

Comment: Please have a look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/hjxcD/
It just works, isn't it?